# Grunt-contrib-connect: how to launch the server in a specified browser

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-connect

I'm quite new to the **bower** / **grunt** / **yeoman** environment. I'm trying to customize the app generated by the default yeoman *Webapp generator*.

Basically when I launch `grunt serve` the default browser will be launched opening the url served by the grunt server. I'd like to specify in which browser the webapp should be opened but I had no luck.

These are the default options of the connect task (using *grunt-contrib-connect*) inside my *gruntfile*:

```
connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            open: true,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost',
        }
```

I've tried to add the field `appName: 'Firefox'` but I think this is not what I'm looking for. I guess the `appName` is used to specify how to lauch the default browser from the command line (e.g. with the `open` command), am I right?

Is it possible to specify the browser in *grunt-contrib-connect* or not at all? If not how should I accomplish this task? Maybe using *grunt-open*?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this commit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/commit/e1d4845c865277ac208d20d65890b699fbceee70) in grunt-contrib-connect
, the `open` option seems to be supported from v0.6.0.
But the app generated webapp generator uses v0.5.0 by default.

So you need to upgrade it in `package.json`.

```
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.7.1",
```

Then run `npm install` (and you can double-check with `npm list | grep grunt-contrib-connect` if v0.7.1 has been installed) and add the `open` option in `Gruntfile.js`.

```
    connect: {
        ...
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: {
                    appName: 'Firefox'
                },
        ...
```

This works for me, so I hope this helps you too.

Comment: Perfect, to be honest the version was already 0.7.1 but I was using the option in the wrong place and in the wrong way. I was wrongly  putting the `appName`  inside `connect: { options: {appName: 'Firefox'}}` thanks